# GitHub Pages not applying CSS but it is working locally

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

The link to CSS is like this: `<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`

GitHub Pages is running off the `/docs` directory.

This is the link to my repository: https://github.com/kunalbotla/universal-resume

[image: Screenshot of Sources in Chrome]

[image: What I see in Atom]

Comment: Check your web console to see where it is trying to reference the stylesheet. You will be able to see where the path is incorrect.

Comment: @DreamTeK I don't think GitHub Pages has a console. It bases everything off of the repository. If so where would I be able to find it?

Comment: @username press `F12`

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com ah, thanks. It says `Failed to load resource: styles.css:1 the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. I can see that it can't find the file (as seen in the image attached to the edited question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GitHub pages, you have to commit the files (in this case `style.css`) to the repository in order for it to work. I see in your repo, there is no style.css file.

You'll need to [remove this](https://github.com/kunalbotla/universal-resume/blob/b847fd53e8bf1d7080246926ca3af82fd00a48b7/.gitignore#L5) from your `.gitignore`, run `npm build` on your local machine, and commit that file to the `docs/` folder.

Comment: That makes sense. Logically I should have looked there, but I guess I missed it when trying everything else I did.